# How to create environment variable SONAR_RUNNER_HOME for sonar (eclipse ) in windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows-7-x64, sonarqube

I am working on eclipse helios and windows 7.

I dont know
1.What needs to be added as a seperator, like ";" , "%" and where?
2. Which directory path of Sonar is to be assigned to the path?

In short I need whole procedure for setting the SONAR_RUNNER_HOME in windows.

Answer (score 5):

**Steps to set environment variables for SONAR_RUNNER_HOME**

Open your environment variables window.
Click new button in System variables section.

1. Set a variable name SONAR_RUNNER_HOME and its value should be the unzipped path of sonar-runner zip file.

   Example:-
   variable name:- SONAR_RUNNER_HOME
   variable value:- C:\Program Files (x86)\sonar-runner
2. And then append sonar-runner's bin path %SONAR_RUNNER_HOME%\bin to the environment variables path.

   Example:-
   variable name:- PATH
   variable value:- %SONAR_RUNNER_HOME%\bin;

Answer (score 2):

You need to open your environment variables first.
You do this by pressing "Winkey" + "Pause" at the same time -> click on "advanced system settings" on the left -> select "environment variables"

**1.What needs to be added as a seperator, like ";" , "%" and where?**

Under Windows ";" (semicolon) is used as seperator. You need to add it at the end of your variable, so you tell windows that another variable begins here. E.g. *"C:/programs/myProgram; C:/programs/anotherProgram"* (have a look at your "PATH" environment variable and you will understand what I mean.)

**2. Which directory path of Sonar is to be assigned to the path?
In short I need whole procedure for setting the SONAR_RUNNER_HOME in windows.**

The following guide is the same as the offical one on this page [Installing and Configuring SonarQube Runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner):

1. Uncompress the downloaded file into the directory of your choice (e.g.: C:\Program Files\SonarRunner). I'll refer to it as  in the next steps.
2. Update the global settings (database connection, server URL) by editing /conf/sonar-runner.properties. (have a look at the link given above)
3. Create a new SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable set to
4. Add the /bin directory to your PATH / Path. (You can either add e.g."C:\Program Files\SonarRunner\bin;" or "%SONAR_RUNNER_HOME%\bin;"). Make sure you add an ";" (semicolon) behind your existing variables as an seperator.
5. You can check the basic installation by opening a new shell and executing the command "sonar-runner -h" (on Windows platform the command is "sonar-runner.bat -h") . For a example please have a look at the link above.

You could also have a look at: [Analyzing with SonarQube Runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner)